# Why do they refer to the main character of this 1951 Disney short as literally "Fat"?

Tags: american-english, history

In the 1951 animated short titled *Tomorrow We Diet**, the main guy (Goofy) is repeatedly referred to as "Fat". Not "being fat", but literally "Fat":

> Hello, Fat!

> Where to, Fat?

> You're just too fat, Fat!

> What'ch you got there, Fat?

> Hey, Fat!

Was this a common way to refer to people in the 1950s? As in, literally using what they are as the "name"?

(It's clear that the character's name isn't actually "Fat", because he is seen as having been slim until recently. Also, he gets offended/upset each time.)

Comment: Comments deleted. Please write an answer in the answer box instead of the comments box.

Comment: Relevant question on Writing Stack Exchange: [Is an uppercase property okay to refer to a person?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/61398/is-an-uppercase-property-okay-to-refer-to-a-person)

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon to refer to people by a physical attribute. If you're being nice, you usually refer to positive attributes. Notice the first line, where Goofy says to his reflection

> Hello, Handsome!

You can find many examples of this phrase in old movies.

The reflection's reply is a play on this, replacing "Handsome" with "Fat" to emphasize Goofy's weight problem.

"Fat" is not commonly used this way, but school kids might tease someone by calling them "Fatty" or "Fatso". Similarly, someone with glasses would be called "Four-eyes", and someone with braces might be called "Metal-mouth".